# SVG performance optimization for browser

Tags: javascript, browser, svg, svg.js

I am working on a design tool using SVG. Any other vector formats will be converted to SVG and rendered on the browser with svg.js

I started seeing delays while dragging and moving the elements, when the number of elements increased.

Are there any ways in which I can improve the SVG performance on the browser?

Also, I want give user the ability to rotate and scale elements, render clip arts and add text. Will this make the performance worse?

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/sreenathn/EcSDn/11/)

You can see that the drag is pretty slow on that element

Comment: I qickly tested and using the CSS trick `transform: translatez(0);` you can get some more performance. Don't over do it, that will also hurt you performance.

Comment: thank you, Nils. I will definitely try that out.

Comment: This has been addressed in svg.js draggable plugin [issue list](https://github.com/wout/svg.draggable.js/issues/10)